# Impala - Find first day on Month from String value

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have data_date column (String data type) in table employee having value in YYYYMMDD format.

Please suggest solution to find first day of month based on data_date column.

for example :

data_Date - 20181217 (String Value)

Output - 20181201 (String Value)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,CONVERT(date, '20170825')), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Substitute your column for date string

Comment: Tried below query and getting error:
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,CONVERT(date, data_as_of_daily_date)), 0) AS StartOfMonthfrom table_name //////////////////////

AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: ...DATEDIFF(month, 0,CONVERT(date, data_as_of_daily_date)... ^ Encountered: DATE Expected: ALL, CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, DISTINCT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: Can you please put your query? Does that column has 'NULL' values?

Comment: Column has only tow values 20181217 and 20181119. I am running below query on Impala and It is throwing error.
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,CONVERT(DATE, data_as_of_daily_date)), 0) AS StartOfMonthfrom table_name

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Do you have any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
select left(data_date, 6) || '01'
```

Comment: I have used the below query to find first date of month and it is returning the result as "2018-12-01 00:00:00"
Expected output - 20181201(String type)

SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')),
1 - DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')))) AS firstdayofmonth
FROM table